# Prevent mv from overwriting the larger file by the same name

Tags: linux, unix, file-management, mv

I need to move all files from a directory, discarding the directory structure.

Unfortunately, some files have the same file name (Thumbnails).
I'm looking for smth. like this:

```
find /tmp/dirtree -type f -exec mv -i {} . \;
```

**How can I prevent the overwriting of larger files during the process?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `mymv.pl` Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Copy;
$file = shift;
($name = $file) =~ s#.*/##;
if (-f $name and -s $file < -s $name) {
     warn "$name not moved";
} else {
     move($file, $name);
}
```

Then, change the line to

```
find /tmp/dirtree -type f -exec perl mymv.pl {} \;
```

Comment: Simple stupid solution means KISS! Please edit your post and add the `perl` parameter after `-exec`. I got curious issues without that. Thank you.

Comment: @msec: Updated.

Comment: This would probably get more upvotes if you explained what it did. At least from me. In the OP's question, it looks like he is moving the files to the current directory "." but I can't tell where you're moving it.